# Mapping with self reference class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I am trying to map the below Employee domain object to EmployeeViewModel using automapper.

I am able to map properties like, Id, FirstName, LastName. But unable to map the Subordinates property.

Used `Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeViewModel>()`, but dont know how to map Subordinates property.

Can anybody please help how to map the below classes.

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int FirstName{get; set;}
  public int LastName{get; set;}
  public Employee Manager{get; set;}
}

public class EmployeeViewModel
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int FirstName{get; set;}
  public int LastName{get; set;}
  public List<Employee> Subordinates {get; set;}
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@helper ShowTree(IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel> emp)
{
<ul>
    @foreach (var e in emp)
    {
        <li>
            @e.FirsyName
            @if (e.Children.Any())
            {
                @ShowTree(e.Children)
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
}
```

Thanks,
-Naren

Comment: Could you elaborate more. Show us your automapping configuration and what error if any you have had?

Comment: I have used  Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeViewModel>();, but i dont know how to map subordinates property.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Employee entity doesnt contain a List property called Subordinates it wont automatically be mapped. To map the to the subordinates property you will need to change your viewmodel subordinates property to the same type, a Employee object called manager.

```
public class Employee()
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int FirstName{get; set;}
    public int LastName{get; set;}
    public Employee Manager {get; set;} 
}

public class EmployeeViewModel()
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int FirstName{get; set;}
    public int LastName{get; set;}
    public Employee Manager {get; set;} 
}
```

But looking above there will be no point mapping the objects as your view directly resembles your domain Employee object. Only use a viewmodel if you require changing your domain entity to represent the view.

Its unclear what you are trying to do, if you display your view then i will be able to assist more.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to build tree view on my view page, for which i am trying to convert Employee to EmployeeViewModel for easy treeview conversion.

Comment: @Narendra V Yes then update your question including your View page code

Comment: Can i also see the action where you load the view model and pass it to the view.